# ABS + tabs + Fragments issue

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have an app with ABS and navigation type tabs. 
In one of the tabs I have 3 fragments (different arrangement portrait/landscape) : one has a list , one has a coverflow and the last has some search functions. When pressing list item or coverflow item or search result I what to open the details fragment which should load as a fragment full screen.
Another concern is that, for every fragment, I have to call a webservice which returns the information to display. But I can't call them in parallel, so I load first the list, than the coverflow, then the search options. Otherwise it gives a server error something like : "connection still allocated".

**Issue**: On configuration changed won't work as expected : as I wan't the detail to be loaded with the desired layout according to the new configuration and also for the three in the backstack and somehow to not have the server error :D

**What I've tried:** 
1) no configChanges attribute for the activity, so the activity is restarting each time . This kind of works for the three fragments but when I have a detail opened it gives me the server error I talked about. Cause it tries to restore all the 3 fragments from backstack and also the detail fragment in the same time.

see logcat output:

06-12 12:31:38.511: E/EvenementsMainActitity(23833): onCreate

06-12 12:31:38.551: E/NouveauLieuxFragment(23833): onCreateView

06-12 12:31:38.561: E/Top5Fragment(23833): onCreateView

06-12 12:31:38.571: E/RechercheFragment(23833): onCreateView

06-12 12:31:38.611: E/SalleDetailsFragment(23833): onCreateView

06-12 12:31:38.641: W/PhoneWindow(23833): Previously focused view reported id 2131099775 during save, but can't be found during restore.

06-12 12:31:38.641: I/EvenementsMainActitity(23833): onResumeFragments

06-12 12:31:38.671: I/EvenementsMainActitity(23833): onTabSelected - Les Tops

06-12 12:31:38.671: E/NouveauLieuxFragment(23833): onCreateView

06-12 12:31:38.681: W/SingleClientConnManager(23833): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.

06-12 12:31:38.681: W/SingleClientConnManager(23833): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

06-12 12:31:38.721: E/Top5Fragment(23833): onCreateView 06-12 12:31:38.731: E/RechercheFragment(23833): onCreateView

06-12 12:31:38.831: I/coverflow(23833): center coverflow 427

06-12 12:31:38.851: E/SalleDetailsFragment(23833): GetSalleById error Server Error

06-12 12:31:38.851: W/System.err(23833): com.neurospeech.wsclient.SoapFaultException: Server Error

- where EvenementsMainActitity is the main activity; NouveauLieuxfragment, Top5Fragment and RechercheFragment are the 3 fragments I was talking about and SalleDetailsFragment is the detail fragment

  - I can't seem to understand why the `oncreateview` of the fragments are called twice :(

2) with configChanges attribute for the activity, so I've written the onConfigurationChanged method, but like I did, it just restores the tab from which I came even if I was in details.

3) now I'm trying to change the details into an activity, but it's is very hard cause I need a bunch of variables and I have to send them through bundle and also I won't have the actionbar etc...

**Note:** I have to display again the activity and fragments on configuration changed cause of the different layouts for orientations.

Let me know I there is more info or code to provide for better understanding.

EDIT: 
I have ONE SherlockFragmentActivity that contains the tabs, and a SherlockFragment for EACH tab and the same for the details.
Than I have :

```
private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final Activity mActivity;

    public MyTabListener(Activity activity, String tag) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, final FragmentTransaction ft) {

        ....

        tab_position = tab.getPosition();

        switch (tab_position) {
           ...
            case 1: // Les Tops

                if (BuildMode.DEBUG) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onTabSelected - Les Tops");
                }

                preInitializedFragment1 = (SherlockFragment) ((SherlockFragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(fragments_mTags.get(2));
                preInitializedFragment2 = (SherlockFragment) ((SherlockFragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag(fragments_mTags.get(10));
                if (!isPhone)
                    preInitializedFragment3 = (SherlockFragment) ((SherlockFragmentActivity) mActivity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentByTag(fragments_mTags.get(8));

                if (preInitializedFragment1 == null && preInitializedFragment2 == null
                        && ((!isPhone && preInitializedFragment3 == null) || isPhone)) {
                    frag1 = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, NouveauLieuxFragment.class.getName());
                    ft.add(R.id.content1, frag1, fragments_mTags.get(2));
                    frag2 = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, Top5Fragment.class.getName());
                    ft.add(R.id.content2, frag2, fragments_mTags.get(10));
                    if (!isPhone) {
                        frag3 = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, RechercheFragment.class.getName());
                        ft.add(R.id.content3, frag3, fragments_mTags.get(8));
                    }
                } else if (frag1 != null && frag2 != null && ((!isPhone && frag3 != null) || isPhone)) {
                    ft.attach(frag1);
                    ft.attach(frag2);
                    if (!isPhone)
                        ft.attach(frag3);
                } else if (preInitializedFragment1 != null && preInitializedFragment2 != null
                        && ((!isPhone && preInitializedFragment3 != null) || isPhone)) {
                    ft.attach(preInitializedFragment1);
                    ft.attach(preInitializedFragment2);
                    frag1 = preInitializedFragment1;
                    frag2 = preInitializedFragment2;
                    if (!isPhone) {
                        ft.attach(preInitializedFragment3);
                        frag3 = preInitializedFragment3;
                    }
                }
                loadLesTops();

                break;
            ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {


        ....

        // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
        if (frag1 != null) {
            ft.detach(frag1);
        }
        if (frag2 != null) {
            ft.detach(frag2);
        }
        if (frag3 != null) {
            ft.detach(frag3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *On configuration changed won't work as expected* - this isn't a clear explanation for the problem. Some code on how you handle those fragments would be good to look at.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need some code to see how you do things.

When using ABS don't use Activity or fragment, you must use SherlockFragmentActivity and SherlockFragment.

You can for exemple have ONE SherlockFragmentActivity that contain your ViewPager or tabs, and a SherlockFragment in EACH tabs.

Your DetailView should be a SherlockFragmentActivity you can pass data with Extra it's the same behavior that bundle with fragments. The ABS can be retreived in every SherlockFragmentActivity with :

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setTitle(R.string.titre_abs);
bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

you go back to your MainActivity by :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.animator.anim_left, R.animator.anim_right);
}
```

Manage your MenuItems with

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

Unless your application require it you should not let activities/fragments refresh on screen rotation. Use :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

When swaping between fragment try not to use "Add", use "Replace".

...
Do you use a TabAdapter class ? a ViewPager ?

**We need your code help more**